# Handling big user IDs returned by FQL in PHP

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to retrieve a list of users from Facebook. For consistency I get the result as JSON. This causes a problem - since the returned JSON encodes the user IDs as numbers, json_decode() converts these numbers to floating point values, because some are too big to fit in an int; of course, I need these IDs as strings.

Since json_decode() does its own thing without accepting any behavior flags, I'm at a loss. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) can convert large integers to strings, if you specify a flag in the function call:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)
```

Comment: No idea how could I miss that in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: This only is in a dev version of PHP - at least according to the documentation on php.net?

Comment: @Sebastian Hoitz , The page has not been updated in a long time, according to it the parameter should be available from PHP 5.3 (which was released a "long" time ago).

Comment: I just tried it on my local computer and got an error that json_decode only accepts 3 parameters.

Comment: Actually, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is [only available since 5.4](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) according to the docs. For earlier versions a preg_replace solution is likely to work best as discussed below - I would do something like `json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString), true)`

Answer (score 20):

I've resolved the issue by adding **`&format=json-strings`** to my the FQL api call, like so:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()";
$facebook->api("/fql?q=" . urlencode($myQuery) . "&format=json-strings")
```

This tells facebook to wrap all the numbers in quotes, which leads json_decode to use neither 
int-s not floats.

Because I was afraid this issue is not restricted to FQL but to all graph API calls that choose to represent some of the IDs as BIG-INTs I've  went as far as patching facebook's PHP SDK a bit to force Facebook to return all of its numbers as strings.

I've added this one line to the `_graph` function.
*This would be line 738 in facebook_base.php, version 3.1.1*

```
$params['format'] = 'json-strings';
```

Sure fix

Comment: This works for those of us who aren't using the latest PHP and thus don't have JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING.

Comment: This was the most solid answer for me. Just in case you stumble across this later:

$myQuery = $facebook->api("/fql", array(
 "q" => "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()",
        "format" => "json-strings"
));

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem where `json_decode` was converting recent twitter/tweet IDs into exponential numbers.

Björn's answer is great if you want your BIGINT to become a string - and have PHP 5.3+. If neither of those things are true, another option is to up PHP's float precision.
This can be done a different few ways...

- find the `precision` value in your php.ini and change it to `precision = 20`
- add `ini_set('precision', 20);` to your PHP app
- add `php_value precision 20` to your app's .htaccess or virtual host file

Comment: Simple and easy. BTW, can we adjust the number '20' so it can accommodate long value?

Comment: I add this line to my .htaccess php_value precision 20. On the first site, this works fine. But when I add this on the other site, I got 500 internal server error. What replacement should I used?

Answer (score 5):

Quick and dirty, seems to work for now :

```
$sJSON = preg_replace('/:(\d+)/', ':"${1}"', $sJSON);
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this and it works almost great.

```
json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString), true)
```

The json breaks when there is geo data included, eg. `{"lat":54.2341}` results in `"lat":"54".2341`

Solution:

```
$json = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)(.\d+)?/', '\\1:"\\2\\3"', $json);
```

Comment: Thanks! That cut it for me! This problem should be fixed soon on Facebook's side though: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254502934666393

Comment: This pattern will also work since it matches digits & dots in one capture group: `preg_replace('/("[\w.]+"):([\d.]+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json);`

Answer (score 0):

This `(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)(.\d+)?/', '\\1:"\\2\\3"', $json);)` worked for me (for parsing result from facebook api)

Answer (score 0):

A major oversight on PHP's part is that browsers don't choke on integers *starting* with BigInt (64 bits), but before that (53 bits). The introduction of BigInt to modern browsers doesn't help much, when JSON does not support it. So I am trying to remedy that.

My approach is to handle the decoded array (before potentially re-encoding it to a string):

```php
function fix_large_int(&$value)
 {
  if (is_int($value) && $value > 9007199254740991)
    $value = strval($value);
 }
$json_arr = json_decode($json_str, flags: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING | JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
echo('before: ' . json_encode($json_arr) . '<br />' . PHP_EOL);
array_walk_recursive($json_arr, 'fix_large_int');
echo('after:  ' . json_encode($json_arr) . '<br />' . PHP_EOL);
```

The number 9007199254740991 is what JavaScript has as its Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER value. Read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

(By the way, I got here, because Twitter API's `stringify_ids` parameter for `blocks/ids` and `friends/ids` does not work for me. There seems to be no mention of that anywhere I could find, though.)