# php json decode number issue

Tags: php, json

I met some trouble in php json decode number.

```
$json = '[{"num":123456789011121314},{"num":1516171819202122232425}]';
$number = json_decode($json);
foreach($number as $num){
    echo $num->num.'<br />';
    //echo (int)$num->num.'<br />';
}
```

this will get:

```
1.23456789011E+17
1.5161718192E+21
```

Also (int) do a wrong callback. And how to get the orignal number? Thanks.

I need

```
123456789011121314    
1516171819202122232425
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.4 or later, you can do this:

`$number = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);`

Which will represent those large numbers as strings instead of ints. If you have access to the code generating the json, you could also encode the numbers as strings.

Comment: Unfortunately that option is PHP 5.4+ though.

Answer (score 1):

Since the json structure is not complicated, we can fix it with a simple regular expression. The idea is to enclose numbers in doublequotes.

```
$json = '[{"num":123456789011121314},{"num":1516171819202122232425}]';
$sanitized = preg_replace('/:(\w*\d+)/', ':"$1"', $json);
$number = json_decode($sanitized);
```

This should work fine for you as did for me.

The pattern matches to a colon followed by some optional whitespace followed by a number.

Comment: Produce invalid JSON for {"test":":3432"}.

Comment: @gimpe Indeed but I don't think that `":3432"` is a valid number. Is it?

Comment: No but it is a valid string. In fact I wanted to warn people to use this regular expression only in specific cases where there is only numbers and you cannot have user input looking like ":number". It almost worked for me :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 128-bit system?

That second number is bigger than even a 64-bit machine can hold as an integer, thus it is being converted to float. Cue precision loss and exponent parts.

Another solution: use smaller numbers.

If you absolutely must have these numbers, look into APIs like [BC-Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).