# How to get around or make PHP json_decode not alter my very large integer values?

Tags: php, json, wamp

So I'm using php 5.2.6 in a WAMP environment.

I'm trying to use the json_decode function to make a json string into an array. The JSON is coming from a REST API elsewhere so I have no control over formatting of the JSON string. Here is an example of one of the json strings I'm trying to use:

```
[{
    "webinarKey":795855906,
    "sessionKey":100000000041808257,
    "startTime":"2011-12-16T13:56:15Z",
    "endTime":"2011-12-16T14:48:37Z",
    "registrantsAttended":2
}]
```

I'm specifically after the sessionKey value here. PHP is treating the value as a float and I can't seem to do anything to retrieve the original value.

I've tried the following:

```
json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
# This produces the following error because my php version isn't up to snuff and I
# can't upgrade to the version required
# Warning: json_decode() expects at most 2 parameters, 4 given
```

I've also tried this:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json, true);
number_format($json_obj[0]["sessionKey"], 0, '.', '');
# This results in precision issues where the value was 100000000041808257
# but is number_formated out as 100000000041808256
```

As I said, upgrading to php 5.4 (where the 4 parameter json_decode call is supported) isn't an option. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a duplicate here on SO somewhere, it might be worth searching

Comment: You might look at this question. A few people listed solutions after the JSON has been returned but before it is decoded. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2907806/2863

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Scott Gottreu and @pospi.

The answer was in the last comment for the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php).

Use the preg_replace() function to surround all integer values with quotes.

```
json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString), true);
```

Actually after testing the above line it screws up JSON with floating point numbers in as values so to fix that issue I used the following to just enclose all numbers (integer or floating point numbers) in quotes:

```
json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+(\.\d+)?)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString), true);
```

Comment: In case you are dealing with negative numbers, just add the `-` symbol as optional in the regexp:  

`$json = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json)`

Answer (score 7):

To quality [JSON](http://www.json.org/) spec use:

```
// wrap numbers
$json = preg_replace('/:\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?([e|E][\-|\+]\d+)?)/', ': "$1"', $json);
// as object
$object = json_decode($json);
// as array
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Wont this corrupt json containing strings with colons and numbers?

Comment: Phil_1984_ yes I think you are right. Specifically it would for a string with a colon and a json integer. I'm guessing you'd need to check for a non escaped double quote prior to the colon to guarantee it not being a string but property.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, PHP has fixed this problem ... well, somehow. Starting sometime around PHP 5.4 they added an option which does the just what the Regex solutions posted above do:

```
json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

The 512 refers to the default maximum nesting depth.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm re-posting my answer from another question ([Handling big user IDs returned by FQL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/)) here, because this is more generic; not related to Facebook / FQL.)

A major oversight on PHP's part is that browsers don't choke on integers *starting* with BigInt (64 bits), but before that (53 bits). The introduction of BigInt to modern browsers doesn't help much, when JSON does not support it. So I am trying to remedy that.

The often cited versions using `preg_replace()` do not account for large integers in indexed arrays. My approach is to handle the decoded array (before potentially re-encoding it to a string):

```php
function fix_large_int(&$value)
 {
  if (is_int($value) && $value > 9007199254740991)
    $value = strval($value);
 }
$json_arr = json_decode($json_str, flags: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING | JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
echo('before: ' . json_encode($json_arr) . '<br />' . PHP_EOL);
array_walk_recursive($json_arr, 'fix_large_int');
echo('after:  ' . json_encode($json_arr) . '<br />' . PHP_EOL);
```

The number 9007199254740991 is what JavaScript has as its Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER value. Read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER