# json_decode is rounding floats, how can I prevent it?

Tags: php, json, decode

I have a rather big json file with coordinates in the following format

```
"[[3.2,1],[4.8,2]]"
```

which represents (3.2,1) and (4.8,2)

I'm using these coördinates to generate a D3 geographic map, but when php is modelling this information into a geoJSONobject I encounter the following error:

I need to transform the coordinates into a array for which I use `json_decode`. However:

```
json_decode("[[3.2,1],[4.8,2]]")
```

returns

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

Where I lose the decimals. How can I prevent this?

### Edit:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": "[[[8.7, 11], [8.89, 12.13],[9.27, 12.13], [9.9, 12], [9.7, 10.8], [8.7, 11]]]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "04",
            "count": "25"
        }
    }]
}
```

This is an example of the data I'm getting as output. (It is supposed to represent a map of rooms which are get a density color by its usage)

I am able to parse this using `jQuery.parseJSON(data)`, but running the following D3 code generates the weirdest errors:

```
val(svgname).append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(geoJSONobject.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    ...
```

[image: error]
I think it's because of the quotes around the array of coordinates.

### Edit (2) - actual solution

The solution I accepted was a workaround, but the true issue was localized php-settings. using:

```
echo json_encode($dataset, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

in the php-file, all the issues were resolved. Though I'd update the question since it is still being looked at (if anyone would encouter the issue)

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? I'm running 5.5.12 and it leaves them as floats.

Comment: I do not know what causes this, but maybe as a workaround: Pass them around as strings maybe,  then cast them to floats when you receive the coordinates.

Comment: The docs (http://php.net/json_decode) do mention casting large integers to floats, but yours don't look very large ;) @ErwinMoller's suggestion of using strings will absolutely work. Whether you're curious about *why* this is happening for you is another matter.

Comment: Looks good for `5.2.0 - 7.0.0alpha2` http://3v4l.org/rtamO#v520
`var_dump()` the var holding the JSON.

Comment: I'm still using php 5.2.4, upgrading is sadly enough not possible... Is it possible to elaborate further on the passing around as strings method?

Comment: It's real simple, he just means store them as strings and when you need to use them, convert them to floats.

Comment: Just wrap the values in quotes: `json_decode('[["3.2","1"],["4.8","2"]]');`

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, as per the SO guidelines. Also, mixing in some jQuery claims doesn't help either to clarify the problem.

Comment: The problem is solved by applying @Travesty3 s solution. I would gladly accept that solution if he would post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the values in quotes: `json_decode('[["3.2","1"],["4.8","2"]]');`

Comment: That's a workaround rather than a solution. It relies on dynamic typing in PHP and/or ECMAScript, where `"3.1"` and `3.1` are interpreted depending on the context. Formally, `"3.1"` in JSON is a string, while `3.1` is a floating-point type, and any JSON decoder worth its name should be able to decode it.

Comment: Well, I guess the solution would be to work with the lastest version of php. Since Tom Jenkins and others confirmed it to be working on their machines. Sadly enough I can't perform the upgrade. Meanwhile this *solved* my problem, which is why I marked it as *solution*.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I solved it using the followin regex

**SOLUTION 1**

```
$yourJsonVariable = preg_replace('/:\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?([e|E][\-|\+]\d+)?)/', ': "$1"', $yourJsonVariable);
```

Convert it into array

```
$array = json_decode($yourJsonVariable, true);
```

Credits goes to this **[SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759314/how-to-get-around-or-make-php-json-decode-not-alter-my-very-large-integer-values)**

**SOLUTION 2**

You can set `ini_set('precision',1);`

**SOLUTION 3**

```
$decoded = json_decode($encoded, true, null, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

> **NOTE:** The Last solution will work only for **PHP > 5.4**

You might want to take a look at this **[Blog](http://manzzup.blogspot.in/2014/06/handle-precision-lose-issue-in.html)**

Comment: Should be marked as correct answer! Proposed as **Solution 1** worked for me like a charm

Comment: After some tests, regex are matching numbers inside quotes  ```/:\s*(?!\B"[^"]*)(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?([e|E][\-|\+]\d+)?)(?![^"]*"\B)/``` this condition will only quote numbers that are not already quoted