# prevent php from parsing floats as floats in json_decode

Tags: php, json

I have some json that i decode using json decode,

however I have floats in the json file, like "58.939020934234" and json_decode parses it as a float (just like it should) however on large numbers its chopping off the ends ( again, like it should ) however this is really bad and I need to find a way to FORCE json_decode to parse EVERYTHING as a string.

I read the documentation and the forth parameter is a flag and we can pass the const JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING which I think is what I need, however when I try this i get an error saying json_decode does not accept 4 arguments! I'm running php5.

Does anybody know of another I could force this json to be parsed as string?

Comment: According to the changelog, the `options` parameter was added in PHP 5.4

Comment: Are you getting the data from a public API? There are a bunch of solutions to a similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php

Comment: PHP 5.4 is officially released now btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `options` parameter was added in PHP 5.4, which isn't stable yet. This from the changelog on the man page for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
5.4.0    The options parameter was added.
```