# JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING backporting

Tags: php, json

From my understanding, `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is 5.4+ only. I need the reproduce the same behavior in 5.1+ environments. The code is meant to be distributed and I have no control over environments it will run on.  What are my options (apart from writing my own json parser)? Is there any established and well-tested solution?

Comment: Perhaps this will work for you ? > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php#comment9450699_2928422

Comment: @Svetlio: thanks, but parsing a structured response with regular expressions is my least option. I'm looking for something more reliable.

Comment: @thg435: Upgrading to PHP 5.4 is more reliable.

Comment: Maybe it would be easy to modify this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.json.introduction.html

Comment: There is also the `json_decode` reimplementation in [`upgradephp`](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/), meant to provide a compatible implemententation on PHP 5.0 and before. But you can also use the prefixed version `up_json_decode()`. And of course `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a quite tricky one one but here is a modified version of [Service_JSON](https://gist.github.com/itspriddle/845016) have been using for a while and it does the trick;

Most `regex` solution would fail this test

```
$json = "[999999999999999999]"; 
var_dump(json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json)));
```

Output

```
array (size=1)
    0 => float 1.0E+18
```

**Using service json**

```
$json = new ServicesJSON();
$var = $json->decode("[999999999999999999]");
var_dump($var);
```

Output

```
array (size=1)
    0 => string '999999999999999999' (length=18)
```

**More Complex Json**

```
$data = '{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "num1":"343434343434343434343",
        "num2":1112222333344455566,
        "num3":[223232331321323,"23232343545454",3434343434334],
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"],
                        "num1":"343434343434343434343",
                        "num2":1112222333344455566,
                        "num3":[223232331321323,"23232343545454",3434343434334]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup",
                    "num1":"343434343434343434343",
                    "num2":1112222333344455566,
                    "num3":[223232331321323,"23232343545454",3434343434334],
                    "num4":[999999999999999999]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';


var_dump($json->decode($data,128));
```

Output

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'glossary' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'title' => string 'example glossary' (length=16)
      public 'num1' => string '343434343434343434343' (length=21)
      public 'num2' => string '1112222333344455566' (length=19)
      public 'num3' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '223232331321323' (length=15)
          1 => string '23232343545454' (length=14)
          2 => string '3434343434334' (length=13)
      public 'GlossDiv' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'title' => string 'S' (length=1)
          public 'GlossList' => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              public 'GlossEntry' => 
                object(stdClass)[6]
                  public 'ID' => string 'SGML' (length=4)
                  public 'SortAs' => string 'SGML' (length=4)
                  public 'GlossTerm' => string 'Standard Generalized Markup Language' (length=36)
                  public 'Acronym' => string 'SGML' (length=4)
                  public 'Abbrev' => string 'ISO 8879:1986' (length=13)
                  public 'GlossDef' => 
                    object(stdClass)[7]
                      ...
                  public 'GlossSee' => string 'markup' (length=6)
                  public 'num1' => string '343434343434343434343' (length=21)
                  public 'num2' => string '1112222333344455566' (length=19)
                  public 'num3' => 
                    array (size=3)
                      ...
                  public 'num4' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      ...
```

**Modified Class**

```
define('SERVICES_JSON_SLICE',   1);
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_STR',  2);
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR',  3);
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ',  4);
define('SERVICES_JSON_IN_CMT', 5);
define('SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE', 16);
define('SERVICES_JSON_SUPPRESS_ERRORS', 32);

class ServicesJSON
{

    function __construct($use = 0)
    {
        $this->use = $use;
    }

    function utf162utf8($utf16)
    {
        // oh please oh please oh please oh please oh please
        if(function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
            return mb_convert_encoding($utf16, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
        }

        $bytes = (ord($utf16{0}) << 8) | ord($utf16{1});

        switch(true) {
            case ((0x7F & $bytes) == $bytes):
                // this case should never be reached, because we are in ASCII range
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0x7F & $bytes);

            case (0x07FF & $bytes) == $bytes:
                // return a 2-byte UTF-8 character
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0xC0 | (($bytes >> 6) & 0x1F))
                     . chr(0x80 | ($bytes & 0x3F));

            case (0xFFFF & $bytes) == $bytes:
                // return a 3-byte UTF-8 character
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0xE0 | (($bytes >> 12) & 0x0F))
                     . chr(0x80 | (($bytes >> 6) & 0x3F))
                     . chr(0x80 | ($bytes & 0x3F));
        }

        // ignoring UTF-32 for now, sorry
        return '';
    }
    function utf82utf16($utf8)
    {
        // oh please oh please oh please oh please oh please
        if(function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
            return mb_convert_encoding($utf8, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
        }

        switch(strlen($utf8)) {
            case 1:
                // this case should never be reached, because we are in ASCII range
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return $utf8;

            case 2:
                // return a UTF-16 character from a 2-byte UTF-8 char
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr(0x07 & (ord($utf8{0}) >> 2))
                     . chr((0xC0 & (ord($utf8{0}) << 6))
                         | (0x3F & ord($utf8{1})));

            case 3:
                // return a UTF-16 character from a 3-byte UTF-8 char
                // see: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                return chr((0xF0 & (ord($utf8{0}) << 4))
                         | (0x0F & (ord($utf8{1}) >> 2)))
                     . chr((0xC0 & (ord($utf8{1}) << 6))
                         | (0x7F & ord($utf8{2})));
        }

        // ignoring UTF-32 for now, sorry
        return '';
    }


    function encode($var)
    {
        switch (gettype($var)) {
            case 'boolean':
                return $var ? 'true' : 'false';

            case 'NULL':
                return 'null';

            case 'integer':
                return (int) $var;

            case 'double':
            case 'float':
                return (float) $var;

            case 'string':
                // STRINGS ARE EXPECTED TO BE IN ASCII OR UTF-8 FORMAT
                $ascii = '';
                $strlen_var = strlen($var);

               /*
                * Iterate over every character in the string,
                * escaping with a slash or encoding to UTF-8 where necessary
                */
                for ($c = 0; $c < $strlen_var; ++$c) {

                    $ord_var_c = ord($var{$c});

                    switch (true) {
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x08:
                            $ascii .= '\b';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x09:
                            $ascii .= '\t';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x0A:
                            $ascii .= '\n';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x0C:
                            $ascii .= '\f';
                            break;
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x0D:
                            $ascii .= '\r';
                            break;

                        case $ord_var_c == 0x22:
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x2F:
                        case $ord_var_c == 0x5C:
                            // double quote, slash, slosh
                            $ascii .= '\\'.$var{$c};
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c >= 0x20) && ($ord_var_c <= 0x7F)):
                            // characters U-00000000 - U-0000007F (same as ASCII)
                            $ascii .= $var{$c};
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xE0) == 0xC0):
                            // characters U-00000080 - U-000007FF, mask 110XXXXX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c, ord($var{$c + 1}));
                            $c += 1;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xF0) == 0xE0):
                            // characters U-00000800 - U-0000FFFF, mask 1110XXXX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}));
                            $c += 2;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xF8) == 0xF0):
                            // characters U-00010000 - U-001FFFFF, mask 11110XXX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 3}));
                            $c += 3;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xFC) == 0xF8):
                            // characters U-00200000 - U-03FFFFFF, mask 111110XX
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 3}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 4}));
                            $c += 4;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;

                        case (($ord_var_c & 0xFE) == 0xFC):
                            // characters U-04000000 - U-7FFFFFFF, mask 1111110X
                            // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                            $char = pack('C*', $ord_var_c,
                                         ord($var{$c + 1}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 2}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 3}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 4}),
                                         ord($var{$c + 5}));
                            $c += 5;
                            $utf16 = $this->utf82utf16($char);
                            $ascii .= sprintf('\u%04s', bin2hex($utf16));
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return '"'.$ascii.'"';

            case 'array':

                // treat as a JSON object
                if (is_array($var) && count($var) && (array_keys($var) !== range(0, sizeof($var) - 1))) {
                    $properties = array_map(array($this, 'name_value'),
                                            array_keys($var),
                                            array_values($var));

                    foreach($properties as $property) {
                        if(ServicesJSON::isError($property)) {
                            return $property;
                        }
                    }

                    return '{' . join(',', $properties) . '}';
                }

                // treat it like a regular array
                $elements = array_map(array($this, 'encode'), $var);

                foreach($elements as $element) {
                    if(ServicesJSON::isError($element)) {
                        return $element;
                    }
                }

                return '[' . join(',', $elements) . ']';

            case 'object':
                $vars = get_object_vars($var);

                $properties = array_map(array($this, 'name_value'),
                                        array_keys($vars),
                                        array_values($vars));

                foreach($properties as $property) {
                    if(ServicesJSON::isError($property)) {
                        return $property;
                    }
                }

                return '{' . join(',', $properties) . '}';

            default:
                return ($this->use & SERVICES_JSON_SUPPRESS_ERRORS)
                    ? 'null'
                    : new ServicesJSON_Error(gettype($var)." can not be encoded as JSON string");
        }
    }


    function name_value($name, $value)
    {
        $encoded_value = $this->encode($value);

        if(ServicesJSON::isError($encoded_value)) {
            return $encoded_value;
        }

        return $this->encode(strval($name)) . ':' . $encoded_value;
    }


    function reduce_string($str)
    {
        $str = preg_replace(array(

                // eliminate single line comments in '// ...' form
                '#^\s*//(.+)$#m',

                // eliminate multi-line comments in '/* ... */' form, at start of string
                '#^\s*/\*(.+)\*/#Us',

                // eliminate multi-line comments in '/* ... */' form, at end of string
                '#/\*(.+)\*/\s*$#Us'

            ), '', $str);

        // eliminate extraneous space
        return trim($str);
    }


    function decode($str)
    {
        $str = $this->reduce_string($str);

        switch (strtolower($str)) {
            case 'true':
                return true;

            case 'false':
                return false;

            case 'null':
                return null;

            default:
                $m = array();

                if (is_numeric($str)) {
                    /**
                     * @todo BIG INT PATH
                     */
                    return $str;

                } elseif (preg_match('/^("|\').*(\1)$/s', $str, $m) && $m[1] == $m[2]) {
                    // STRINGS RETURNED IN UTF-8 FORMAT
                    $delim = substr($str, 0, 1);
                    $chrs = substr($str, 1, -1);
                    $utf8 = '';
                    $strlen_chrs = strlen($chrs);

                    for ($c = 0; $c < $strlen_chrs; ++$c) {

                        $substr_chrs_c_2 = substr($chrs, $c, 2);
                        $ord_chrs_c = ord($chrs{$c});

                        switch (true) {
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\b':
                                $utf8 .= chr(0x08);
                                ++$c;
                                break;
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\t':
                                $utf8 .= chr(0x09);
                                ++$c;
                                break;
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\n':
                                $utf8 .= chr(0x0A);
                                ++$c;
                                break;
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\f':
                                $utf8 .= chr(0x0C);
                                ++$c;
                                break;
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\r':
                                $utf8 .= chr(0x0D);
                                ++$c;
                                break;

                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\\"':
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\\\'':
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\\\\':
                            case $substr_chrs_c_2 == '\\/':
                                if (($delim == '"' && $substr_chrs_c_2 != '\\\'') ||
                                   ($delim == "'" && $substr_chrs_c_2 != '\\"')) {
                                    $utf8 .= $chrs{++$c};
                                }
                                break;

                            case preg_match('/\\\u[0-9A-F]{4}/i', substr($chrs, $c, 6)):
                                // single, escaped unicode character
                                $utf16 = chr(hexdec(substr($chrs, ($c + 2), 2)))
                                       . chr(hexdec(substr($chrs, ($c + 4), 2)));
                                $utf8 .= $this->utf162utf8($utf16);
                                $c += 5;
                                break;

                            case ($ord_chrs_c >= 0x20) && ($ord_chrs_c <= 0x7F):
                                $utf8 .= $chrs{$c};
                                break;

                            case ($ord_chrs_c & 0xE0) == 0xC0:
                                // characters U-00000080 - U-000007FF, mask 110XXXXX
                                //see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                                $utf8 .= substr($chrs, $c, 2);
                                ++$c;
                                break;

                            case ($ord_chrs_c & 0xF0) == 0xE0:
                                // characters U-00000800 - U-0000FFFF, mask 1110XXXX
                                // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                                $utf8 .= substr($chrs, $c, 3);
                                $c += 2;
                                break;

                            case ($ord_chrs_c & 0xF8) == 0xF0:
                                // characters U-00010000 - U-001FFFFF, mask 11110XXX
                                // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                                $utf8 .= substr($chrs, $c, 4);
                                $c += 3;
                                break;

                            case ($ord_chrs_c & 0xFC) == 0xF8:
                                // characters U-00200000 - U-03FFFFFF, mask 111110XX
                                // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                                $utf8 .= substr($chrs, $c, 5);
                                $c += 4;
                                break;

                            case ($ord_chrs_c & 0xFE) == 0xFC:
                                // characters U-04000000 - U-7FFFFFFF, mask 1111110X
                                // see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
                                $utf8 .= substr($chrs, $c, 6);
                                $c += 5;
                                break;

                        }

                    }

                    return $utf8;

                } elseif (preg_match('/^\[.*\]$/s', $str) || preg_match('/^\{.*\}$/s', $str)) {
                    // array, or object notation

                    if ($str{0} == '[') {
                        $stk = array(SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR);
                        $arr = array();
                    } else {
                        if ($this->use & SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE) {
                            $stk = array(SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ);
                            $obj = array();
                        } else {
                            $stk = array(SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ);
                            $obj = new stdClass();
                        }
                    }

                    array_push($stk, array('what'  => SERVICES_JSON_SLICE,
                                           'where' => 0,
                                           'delim' => false));

                    $chrs = substr($str, 1, -1);
                    $chrs = $this->reduce_string($chrs);

                    if ($chrs == '') {
                        if (reset($stk) == SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR) {
                            return $arr;

                        } else {
                            return $obj;

                        }
                    }

                    //print("\nparsing {$chrs}\n");

                    $strlen_chrs = strlen($chrs);

                    for ($c = 0; $c <= $strlen_chrs; ++$c) {

                        $top = end($stk);
                        $substr_chrs_c_2 = substr($chrs, $c, 2);

                        if (($c == $strlen_chrs) || (($chrs{$c} == ',') && ($top['what'] == SERVICES_JSON_SLICE))) {
                            // found a comma that is not inside a string, array, etc.,
                            // OR we've reached the end of the character list
                            $slice = substr($chrs, $top['where'], ($c - $top['where']));


                            /**
                             * @todo patch slice
                             */
                            is_numeric($slice) and $slice = "\"$slice\"";
                            array_push($stk, array('what' => SERVICES_JSON_SLICE, 'where' => ($c + 1), 'delim' => false));
                            //print("Found split at {$c}: ".substr($chrs, $top['where'], (1 + $c - $top['where']))."\n");

                            if (reset($stk) == SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR) {
                                // we are in an array, so just push an element onto the stack
                                array_push($arr, $this->decode($slice));

                            } elseif (reset($stk) == SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ) {
                                // we are in an object, so figure
                                // out the property name and set an
                                // element in an associative array,
                                // for now
                                $parts = array();

                                if (preg_match('/^\s*(["\'].*[^\\\]["\'])\s*:\s*(\S.*),?$/Uis', $slice, $parts)) {
                                    // "name":value pair
                                    $key = $this->decode($parts[1]);
                                    $val = $this->decode($parts[2]);

                                    if ($this->use & SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE) {
                                        $obj[$key] = $val;
                                    } else {
                                        $obj->$key = $val;
                                    }
                                } elseif (preg_match('/^\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\S.*),?$/Uis', $slice, $parts)) {
                                    // name:value pair, where name is unquoted
                                    $key = $parts[1];
                                    $val = $this->decode($parts[2]);

                                    if ($this->use & SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE) {
                                        $obj[$key] = $val;
                                    } else {
                                        $obj->$key = $val;
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        } elseif ((($chrs{$c} == '"') || ($chrs{$c} == "'")) && ($top['what'] != SERVICES_JSON_IN_STR)) {
                            // found a quote, and we are not inside a string
                            array_push($stk, array('what' => SERVICES_JSON_IN_STR, 'where' => $c, 'delim' => $chrs{$c}));
                            //print("Found start of string at {$c}\n");

                        } elseif (($chrs{$c} == $top['delim']) &&
                                 ($top['what'] == SERVICES_JSON_IN_STR) &&
                                 ((strlen(substr($chrs, 0, $c)) - strlen(rtrim(substr($chrs, 0, $c), '\\'))) % 2 != 1)) {
                            // found a quote, we're in a string, and it's not escaped
                            // we know that it's not escaped becase there is _not_ an
                            // odd number of backslashes at the end of the string so far
                            array_pop($stk);
                            //print("Found end of string at {$c}: ".substr($chrs, $top['where'], (1 + 1 + $c - $top['where']))."\n");

                        } elseif (($chrs{$c} == '[') &&
                                 in_array($top['what'], array(SERVICES_JSON_SLICE, SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR, SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ))) {
                            // found a left-bracket, and we are in an array, object, or slice
                            array_push($stk, array('what' => SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR, 'where' => $c, 'delim' => false));
                            //print("Found start of array at {$c}\n");

                        } elseif (($chrs{$c} == ']') && ($top['what'] == SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR)) {
                            // found a right-bracket, and we're in an array
                            array_pop($stk);
                            //print("Found end of array at {$c}: ".substr($chrs, $top['where'], (1 + $c - $top['where']))."\n");

                        } elseif (($chrs{$c} == '{') &&
                                 in_array($top['what'], array(SERVICES_JSON_SLICE, SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR, SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ))) {
                            // found a left-brace, and we are in an array, object, or slice
                            array_push($stk, array('what' => SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ, 'where' => $c, 'delim' => false));
                            //print("Found start of object at {$c}\n");

                        } elseif (($chrs{$c} == '}') && ($top['what'] == SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ)) {
                            // found a right-brace, and we're in an object
                            array_pop($stk);
                            //print("Found end of object at {$c}: ".substr($chrs, $top['where'], (1 + $c - $top['where']))."\n");

                        } elseif (($substr_chrs_c_2 == '/*') &&
                                 in_array($top['what'], array(SERVICES_JSON_SLICE, SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR, SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ))) {
                            // found a comment start, and we are in an array, object, or slice
                            array_push($stk, array('what' => SERVICES_JSON_IN_CMT, 'where' => $c, 'delim' => false));
                            $c++;
                            //print("Found start of comment at {$c}\n");

                        } elseif (($substr_chrs_c_2 == '*/') && ($top['what'] == SERVICES_JSON_IN_CMT)) {
                            // found a comment end, and we're in one now
                            array_pop($stk);
                            $c++;

                            for ($i = $top['where']; $i <= $c; ++$i)
                                $chrs = substr_replace($chrs, ' ', $i, 1);

                            //print("Found end of comment at {$c}: ".substr($chrs, $top['where'], (1 + $c - $top['where']))."\n");

                        }

                    }

                    if (reset($stk) == SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR) {
                        return $arr;

                    } elseif (reset($stk) == SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ) {
                        return $obj;

                    }

                }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @todo Ultimately, this should just call PEAR::isError()
     */
    function isError($data, $code = null) {
        if (is_object($data) && (get_class($data) == 'ServicesJSON_Error' || is_subclass_of($data, 'ServicesJSON_Error'))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
class ServicesJSON_Error {
    function ServicesJSON_Error($message = 'unknown error', $code = null, $mode = null, $options = null, $userinfo = null) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this decodes both JSON strings and numbers to strings, effectively losing information in the process. How is it possible to know what type the decoded value has?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php#comment9450699_2928422):

> Actually, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is [only available since 5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) according to the docs. For earlier versions a preg_replace solution is likely to work best as discussed below - I would do something like `json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $jsonString), true)` – [pospi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141881/pospi) Oct 14 '11 at 4:43

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.class.php](http://code.google.com/p/phplutils/source/browse/trunk/JSON.class.php) from [phputils](http://code.google.com/p/phplutils/) project.

```
class JSON {
    protected $t, $c;
    protected $debug;
    protected $useArrays = false;

    static public function decode($s, $array = false, $debug = false) {
        //return json_decode($s, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
        //return json_decode($s, $array);

        // Version >= 5.4.x will suppoort JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING parameter.
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.99', '>=')) {
            return json_decode($s, $array, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
        }
        // Not supported JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING so we will use our class.
        else {
            try {
                $d = new JSON($s);
                $d->useArrays = $array;
                $d->setDebug($debug);
                return $d->parseObject(512);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    static public function encode($object) {
        return json_encode($object);
    }

    public function __construct($s) {
        $this->setInput($s);
    }

    public function setInput($s) {
        $vv = array_map(function($a) { return isset($a[1]) ? $a[1] : $a; }, token_get_all('<?php ' . $s));
        $this->t = array_values(array_splice($vv, 1));
        $this->c = 0;
        if ($this->debug) print_r($this->t);
    }

    public function setDebug($debug) {
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }

    protected function getCurrentToken() {
        if ($this->c >= count($this->t)) throw(new Exception("EOF"));
        return $this->t[$this->c];
    }

    protected function nextToken() {
        $this->c++;
    }

    protected function parseString() {
        $ct = $this->getCurrentToken();
        if ($ct[0] != '"') throw(new Exception("JSON: Expecting String but found '" . $ct . "'"));
        $this->nextToken();
        //return stripcslashes(substr($ct, 1, -1));
        return json_decode($ct);
    }

    protected function expectValues($values = array()) {
        $ct = $this->getCurrentToken();
        foreach ($values as $value) if ($ct == $value) {
            $this->nextToken();
            return $ct;
        }
        throw(new Exception("JSON: Expecting [" . implode(', ', array_map(function($a) { return "'{$a}'"; }, $values)) . "]"));
    }

    protected function parseNumber() {
        $ct = $this->getCurrentToken();
        if (!is_numeric($ct)) throw(new Exception("JSON: Expecting a number but found '" . $ct . "'"));
        $this->nextToken();
        if ((string)(int)$ct == (string)$ct) {
            return (int)$ct;
        }
        return $ct;
    }

    protected function parseObject($depth = 512) {
        $ret = NULL;
        if ($depth == -1) throw(new Exception("JSON: Depth too long"));
        $ct = $this->getCurrentToken();
        if ($this->debug) echo "--$ct\n";
        switch ($ct[0]) {
            // Object
            case '{':
                $ret = array();
                $this->nextToken();
                if ($this->getCurrentToken() != '}') {
                    do {
                        $key = $this->parseString();
                        if ($this->debug) echo "---key:$key\n";

                        $this->expectValues(array(':'));

                        $value = $this->parseObject($depth - 1);
                        if ($this->debug) echo "---value:$value\n";

                        $ct = $this->expectValues(array(',', '}'));

                        $ret[$key] = $value;
                    } while ($ct == ',');
                } else {
                    $this->nextToken();
                }
                if (!$this->useArrays) $ret = (object)$ret;
            break;
            // Array
            case '[':
                $ret = array();
                $this->nextToken();
                if ($this->getCurrentToken() != ']') {
                    do {
                        $value = $this->parseObject();
                        if ($this->debug) echo "---value:$value\n";
                        $ct = $this->expectValues(array(',', ']'));
                        $ret[] = $value;
                    } while ($ct == ',');
                } else {
                    $this->nextToken();
                }
                //while ()
            break;
            // String
            case '"':
                $ret = $this->parseString();
            break;
            default:
                if (is_numeric($ct[0])) {
                    $ret = $this->parseNumber();
                } else {
                    switch ($ct) {
                        case "null": $this->nextToken(); return NULL;
                        //case "undefined": $this->nextToken(); return NULL;
                        case "true": $this->nextToken(); return true;
                        case "false": $this->nextToken(); return false;
                        default: throw(new Exception("JSON: Invalid object"));
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    static public function unittest() {
        $test = function($expr) {
            $a = JSON::decode($expr);
            $b = json_decode($expr, true);
            var_dump($a === $b);
            if ($a != $b) {
                var_dump($a);
                var_dump($b);
            }
            $a2 = JSON::encode($a);
            $b2 = JSON::encode($b);
            var_dump($a2 === $b2);
            //print_r($a);
            //print_r($b);
        };

        $test2 = function($expr, $b) {
            $a = JSON::decode($expr);
            var_dump($a === $b);
            if ($a != $b) {
                var_dump($a);
                var_dump($b);
            }
            //var_export($a);
        };

        // Empty object.
        $test('{}');

        // Simple object
        $test('{"a":"b"}');

        // Object with comma separated items.
        $test('{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}');

        // Simple object with numbers
        $test('{"k1":1,"k2":2}');

        // Simple array with numbers
        $test('[1,2,3,4]');

        $test('"\\u10000"');

        // Array with langbuage's constants.
        $test('[3,false,true,null]');

        // Complex array with subobjects.
        $test('[{},{"a":{"b":1}},3,false,{"test":true}]');

        // Complex array.
        $test2(
            '{"order_id":131608840232655,"buyer":100001738131058,"app":118178464915404,"receiver":100001738131058,"amount":2,"update_time":1292862324,"time_placed":1292862322,"data":"","items":[{"item_id":"0","title":"[Test Mode] Unicorn","description":"[Test Mode] Own your own mythical beast!","image_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/gifts\/21.png","product_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/images\/gifts\/21.png","price":2,"data":"{\"product_id\":1}"}],"status":"placed"}',
            array (
                'order_id' => '131608840232655',
                'buyer' => '100001738131058',
                'app' => '118178464915404',
                'receiver' => '100001738131058',
                'amount' => 2,
                'update_time' => 1292862324,
                'time_placed' => 1292862322,
                'data' => '',
                'items' => array (
                    0 => array (
                        'item_id' => '0',
                        'title' => '[Test Mode] Unicorn',
                        'description' => '[Test Mode] Own your own mythical beast!',
                        'image_url' => 'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png',
                        'product_url' => 'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png',
                        'price' => 2,
                        'data' => '{"product_id":1}',
                    ),
                ),
                'status' => 'placed',
            )
        );
    }

    static public function _unittest() {
        if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == basename(__FILE__)) {
            JSON::unittest();
        }
    }
}

function json_decode_fixed($s, $debug = false) {
    return JSON::decode($s, $debug);
}

JSON::_unittest();
```