# How to handle unsigned int32 data coming from FQL Stream table for actor_id attribute?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
$query =  "SELECT post_id,actor_id,message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 222104997886913 LIMIT 5 "
```

I am using 2 different types of Facebook Api calls

```
1. $results = $facebook -> api('/fql?query='.urlencode($query).'&access_token=XXX');

2. $results = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?query='.urlencode($query).'&access_token=XXX'));
```

I get all  the data correct in both case, but in case 2 , I get " 2.2210499788691E+14 " this type of actor id. This actor id is fine showing " 222104997886913 " in 1st call. and is showing " unsigned int32 " in 2nd call as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream.

I want to use the 2nd api call and get the full accurate " 222104997886913 " actor id instead of " 2.2210499788691E+14 " for actor_id attribute.

What my masters suggest for this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907806/handling-big-user-ids-returned-by-fql-in-php

Comment: I am thankful to you form core of my heart. You saved my week search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you. Try this
$array = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)